# how to access route /message via web hook when using ngrok

Tags: twilio

Just wondering if anyone has implemented method based routing in TWilio SMS api. the example provided calls a web hook and not a route. Might be because I'm using my the ngrok tunnel to open up port 3000, but I need to test with different route paths

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here. ngrok opens a tunnel to the entire application that is running on the port you select. So, if you have built your endpoint to receive messages at /messages, then to test you should set the webhook for your number to YOUR_NGROK_SUBDOMAIN.ngrok.io/messages. Does that make sense or is there another issue?

Comment: yep that makes sense. tried the wrong url. thanks. works fine